# Why is Fritzbox 7141 not working in a specific room?

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking, fritzbox

I am struggeling with a LAN/WAN/WLAN configuration that fails to work. I have created a network map to clarify shown below. What I am trying here is to provide a good WIFI connection in different rooms of a house.

**Devices:**

- Technicolor Router (Provider-owned, DHCP Server, WLAN, Switch)
- Fritzbox #1 Model 7170 (static IP, no DHCP, WLAN in Room 1, SSID
  "P1", Channel 7)
- Fritzbox #2 Model 7141 (static IP, no DHCP, WLAN in Room 2, SSID "P1", Channel 12)
- D-Link Switch
- different clients

**Network Configuration Picture:**
[image: Network Configuration Picture]

Let me explain the default configuration, steps taken and what the different colors / configurations in the picture mean:

I use three WLAN access points with the same SSID and security configuration to allow ongoing connection of devices through the house wherever they are/go. This basically works very well between Technicolor WLAN and Fritzbox#1, I never even notice the connection switch between those when changing the location. The Router provided by the internet provider has the local IP 192.168.0.1 and has DHCP service activated starting with 192.168.0.100.

I connect the additional WLAN access points on first floor to the wired LAN and reuse the central internet connection. The WLAN access points both are FritzBoxes. They both have a static IP address: 192.168.0.11 and 12. Previously I have used 192.168.0.2/3 for those but I realized those are anyhow used by the Technicolor Router as well (looks like they are used alternating in a round about 30 seconds interval, I do not know the reason or sense of this) so I changed the static IPs for the FritzBoxes to 11 / 12. I double checked their configuration and see no differences in Wifi / LAN / internet connection settings.

The blue parts in the picture show the default / constant configuration. Fritzbox 1 (192.168.0.11) always works properly. FritzBox 2 (192.168.0.12) does not work as expected. It is used in two different configurations (red / black) as follows:

**Configuration RED:** I added the 2nd Fritzbox (FritzBox 2: 192.168.0.12) as WLAN access point in another room. It is configured the same way as the FritzBox 1. Devices (Android 1 / Laptop1) can connect to Wifi, but they do not get a dynamic IP address from the Router (DHCP turned off and managed my technicolor). So the connection is restricted to the fritzbox only. The other way round, PC1 (that is properly connected) also is not able to ping fritzbox2 in this case.

To figure out what is wrong I checked the patch cable used and also the wires from the RJ45 plug to the room where the Router is placed. I plugged another laptop into the RJ45 port in the right room (this is not in the picture). The laptop got an DHCP IP address and had LAN/WAN connection. So I do not see a LAN cable issue here and can't identify the problem.

**Configuration BLACK:** For further tests and to figure out if I have a configuration issue with FritzBox 2, I carried FritzBox 2 into the left room and plugged it into the switch. By using a WLAN Test App on my android, I could make sure to use exactly FritzBox 2 with Channel 12 to establish a WiFi Connection. LAN/WLAN & WAN connection works as expected in configuration Black.

**Side notes:** I did NOT use WDS on the FritzBoxes. Maybe this is worth another try but before changing the scenario I want to know what my issue is.

**Conclusions:** The only difference between Config RED and BLACK is the connection through to small switch placed in the left room.

I have spent hours and hours but I can't find the reason. Please help me, this is still an issue in May 2016.

Comment: Did you use the LAN port on the 7141 to connect in both cases? Also, have you tried connecting the 7141 to the "RJ45" in the other room (i.e. the port the "Switch" is connected to)? With the exact cable you used in the room of Config Red.

Comment: It could be the type of cable (crossover v.s. straight through); or the RJ45 port of Red Config (and/or the cable et. al. connecting it to the Technicolor Router) is broken.

Comment: @TomYan I did not use a cross over cable anywhere, this is for sure. But I didn't try to use the 7141 exactly in that port of the switch. That's something to check, I will try.

Answer (score 1):

You gave an effort to solve this, but you did not check everything/you have not tried every combination. I would debug your config in following order (I've used at least 10 Fritzboxes and they are quite nice product, hardware issue is not very likely but you will not know for sure until you find the cause of problem):

1. You wrote that you tried/checked network cable by using laptop. Try it using Fritzbox, ping it, it should respond. If you get no response, problem found in first step, change straight cable for crossover or opposite (although all Fritzboxes I used had MDI/MDI-X autosensing).
2. If cabling is OK, switch Fritzbox 1 and 2, it shouldn't be too hard to change configuration if you have problem for months and you really want to solve it. Here you'll probably find cause of problem.
3. If cables are OK, and you can switch two Fritzboxes (with appropriate config  change) and problem persists, than problem is most probably of logical nature, somewhere in configuration.

If 1st and 2nd step fail, ask some of your friends to come and to look config settings, as sometimes it is not enough to be clever, as you can miss some obvious error if you do not spot it at first.
Hopefully you'll find problem in first or second step, if not, write every, I mean EVERY setting of both Fritzboxes either to paper or better to text document, print it, and check that you wrote everything right.
If previous steps fail, I'm pretty sure this won't.

Comment: I will give that a try, although I wont be able to do this within next days. Although I already tried and checked everything you recommend and there are no issues with cables and checked the configuration lots of times, I never tried to run the 7170 in the right room (switch them). I will try asap.